# Aliasing a user (id) in CentOS7/8

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, centos7, authentication, centos8

I am in the process of replacing some apache instances with nginx (for performance, mostly). For some time I will need to switch from one to the other. The packagers, in their infinite wisdom, decided to use diiferent user/group IDs for the two servers (nginx/nginx and apache/apache: probably using the same for both - httpd/httpd, say - would have been too mundane).

That's a royal PITA (because all permissions are tuned to apache and I don't want to CHOWN back and forth as I switch between servers). So I want to alias user/group nginx to apache by giving them the same IDs. I've done it in the past, so I know that

- it's possible and
- to some extent it works

But it was years ago and I do not know if intervening OS changes may bite my ass sometime in the future (the idea is that at some point I will toss apache completely, user, group and all but permissions and stuff will still apply to user/group nginx).

So the question is, is this still doable and are there pitfalls I do not know of?

TIA.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Why are _any_ of your web documents owned by the apache user?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because php applications need to write to select parts of the filesystem (e.g. wp-contents/uploads for wordpress) and that happens with whatever user the webserver (or, the fastcgi subsystem, php-fpm) runs under. That's pretty standard, if unsavory.

Comment: OK, it is normal for web uploads to be owned by PHP. In the nginx php-fpm setup they'll be owned by the php user. You may as well chown them. It's just a one-time thing. I personally use ACLs to manage permissions for web files, so I'll have to see if I can dig up what I've previously written about that.